# How to make list fits content when using position absolute

Tags: html, css

How can I make this list fit his content when it has position absolute to parent?

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>easdas da dsad asd as</li>
    <li>fdsf dsf sd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: I want to achieve this (realised by adding `width: 140px;` to `ul`):
[image]

EDIT2: Is there a solution without `white-space:nowrap` in order to be able to set a `max-width` to `li`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `li` elements.

Comment: Do you want your dots to be wrapped by the background color, otherwise I do not understand this clearly

Comment: If you want the ul to fill the div, set the ul's width to 100%. Otherwise I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `white-space:nowrap` to the list item rules:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  background: red;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>easdas da dsad asd as</li>
    <li>fdsf dsf sd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a solution without `white-space:nowrap` in order to be able to set a `max-width` to `li`?

Comment: `min-width` yes, `max-width` not that I'm aware of since you're using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking but I think you're wanting to add the property:
left: 0;
inside the ul element and setting your margin and padding to zero so your elements will fit inside your div though you might want to add width: 100%; to the unordered list so it'll be fixed to the parent element.

EDIT:

This should work if you want to break the context when the text reaches your width though if you dont want to see the text on the second line you could specify height.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  background: red;
  max-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>easdas da dsad asd as</li>
    <li>fdsf dsf sd</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the 100px in the CSS on the div tag.

Live Example --> https://jsfiddle.net/431u1doe/

//CSS

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
}
li {
    background: red;
}
```

You can do this by chaging the width to 100%